# How to create sunburst effect on Adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I would like to create an sunburst effect as in the attached image. I want the flare to be from bigger to smaller (top to bottom)[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jft5y.jpg). I can get the vice versa effect but i wanted something like in this image [Click here for sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FLMZ.jpg). Please guide me how to create it. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is not about programming as stated in the [help/on-topic]. It may better fit on [graphicdesign.se], but make sure to include an image of your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a star with a 0 inner diameter and as many points as you want
   "bursts".
2. Put a rectangle over the star but not past the points of
   the star.
3. Select them both and click divide in the pathfinder
   pallet.
4. Ungroup the resulting paths.
5. Select every other triangle and delete it.
6. yay!!! sunburst.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @TinMonkey. Helps me to create nice sunburst